# Getting errors with linking QuartzCore

Tags: iphone, objective-c, linker, quartz-graphics

I am new with Objective C and iPhone development but that is what I am trying to do... Problem is with QuartzCore and basic animation stuff. These lines are from my `applicationDelegate`:

```
#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"
...
-(void)performTransition {

        if(!transitioning) {

            CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
            transition.duration = 0.9;
            transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
            transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
            transition.subtype = (isInMainDialog) ? kCATransitionFromRight : kCATransitionFromLeft;

            transitioning = YES;
            transition.delegate = self;
        [window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

            if (isInMainDialog) {
                mainController.view.hidden = YES;
                levelController.view.hidden = NO;
                isInMainDialog = false;

                // start game
                [levelController playLevel:1 balls:3 scores:0];
            }
            else {
                mainController.view.hidden = NO;
                levelController.view.hidden = YES;
                isInMainDialog = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

okay.. This applicationDelegate compiles ok, but when building following errors happen:

> "_kCATransitionFromRight", referenced from:
>         _kCATransitionFromRight$non_lazy_ptr in eBreakAppDelegate.o
>
> "_kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut", referenced from:
>         _kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut$non_lazy_ptr in eBreakAppDelegate.o
>
> "_kCATransitionMoveIn", referenced from:
>         _kCATransitionMoveIn$non_lazy_ptr in eBreakAppDelegate.o
>
> ".objc_class_name_CAMediaTimingFunction", referenced from:
>         literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@CAMediaTimingFunction in eBreakAppDelegate.o
>
> "_kCATransitionFromLeft", referenced from:
>         _kCATransitionFromLeft$non_lazy_ptr in eBreakAppDelegate.o
>
> ".objc_class_name_CATransition", referenced from:
>         literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@CATransition in eBreakAppDelegate.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

So, I guess there is a problem in linking, because there is no problems at compile time. Should I, some how, link the quartz to my project or how could this be fixed?

Answer (score 4):

you have to add QuartzCore.framework to your target:

- right click on application target;
- click on [Get Info] in contextual menu;
- in [General] tab there's gonna be two lists, one for dependencies, other for Linked libraries;
- add QuartzCore framework to the botom one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that QuartzCore is added to your project then change this line:

```
#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"
```

to:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

The quotations tell the linker to look in the project source files. The '< >' tell it to look for frameworks.